# Accessing multiple nested static objects

Tags: java, static, nested

I want to create a set of classes that allows me to write records

What I want to achieve is this

```
Record.write.field1();
Record.write.field2();
```

My understanding is that I can create multiple static nested objects but I'm struggling with it

I created the following

```
public abstract class Record{
public Write write;
}
public abstract class Write{
public static void field1();
}
```

The approach above hasn't helped me achieve that.

The questions I have is

Can I write a set of classes in a way so I can achieve the following pattern

```
Record.write.field1();
Record.write.field2();
```

This is so that I can scale it up when needing to add additional field

If I can, is this a good approach?

If I can't, what's the best approach?
Thank you

UPDATE: I can do Record.write but can't do Record.write.field15();

```
public class Record {
    public static Write write;
}

public class Write {
    public static void field15(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: A method in an abstract class cannot be ended with semicolon unless stated as a abstract method. Fix your code on method `field1()` by either adding a body or changing method modifiers to `public abstract`.

Comment: Adding to what @Futarimiti says (which indeed fixes your issue), you can't call `Record.write` because that would mean that `write` is a static field of the class `Record`. Either you make it static, or you need to create an instance of `Record` to do what you want to do.

Comment: The question really is how to organise my classes so that I can use the following approach Record.write.field1(); Is this achievable ?

Comment: It is achievable by doing the 2 changes we suggested. First, the method field1() should either contain a body, or be declared abstract. Second, the instance of Write held by Record should be static.

Comment: I've updated the code but still can't get what the pattern I want to achieve.

Comment: @Sgr Did you declare both classes in the same file? You can only make one public class declaration per file with the same name as the filename. Just change either or both class declarations from `public class` to normal `class` and it should compile.

Comment: I see you calling static method `field15` from `Write` instance `Record.write`. Though java permits this, it is better to [access a static method in a static way](https://www.intertech.com/a-static-method-should-be-accessed-in-a-static-way/) or it could lead to confusions. Or instead, make it a instance method.

Comment: I did not declare both classes in the same file. these are two classes in their own files. are you saying I should be having both classes in the same file ie nested/inner class?

Comment: You can do that but it’s not necessary. Did the code still not compile? What happens when you call `Record.write.field15();` in the main method?

Comment: i can't  call it. it lets me call Record.write only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249731/discussion-between-futarimiti-and-sgr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows you to write the code the way you want:

```
class Record {
    public static Write write = new Write();
}

class Write {
    public void field15(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Record.write.field15(); // prints "Hello"
    }
}
```

Note that static methods are invoked on the class name, and instance methods are invoked on a specific instance value.